# android + javascript : create html dynamically and put javascript in the head tag

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have android application and I need to show banner in some specific manner.

I get the javascript code like this from the server :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://rm.face.ua/adriver.core.2.js"></script>
  <div id="adriver_top"></div><script type="text/javascript">   
   new adriver("adriver_top", {sid: 196260, bt:52, pz:1, bn:0});
</script>
```

I use javascript like this :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:bannerDownload();");
```

so I need to put my javascript code to the javascript method and create dynamically html there and put this javascript to the head of html.
I know, that is not so difficult for web-developers, but I'm deal with Java so need your help. Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with the loadData. Thanks to alexbrickwedde.

But the key is to use like this:

```
webView.loadData(videoUrl, null, null);
```

Because in another cases like this :

```
webView.loadData(videoUrl, "text/javascript", "UTF-8");
```

it didn't work for me. And also don't forget enable Javascript :

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

With loadData, you can easily load content into the WebView.

See Android API Docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

And a sample at heading 5:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: yeah, thank you, I tried this, but doesn't work properly for me. It just put the javascript code into the WebView, but doesn't display the  image...

Comment: You'll have to put the complete content of the first code block from your question into the methods first parameter. Then it should work.

If you put any other valid html into the WebView via this method, does that work?

Comment: I've got it. I added the solution as an answer. Thank you that showed me a direction to search...)